# jquery validation: call ajax and close bootstrap modal form after entire form validates

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using Bootstrap layout and [the jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). I click on a button, a modal with the form opens. The user inputs some data and improves it until everything is correct. When he submits it, it should make `ajax` call and close the modal form (but if the validation fails, there should be no ajax and no modal closing). Below is my code:

ajax call

```
$('#outcomeFormDialog form').on( "submit", function( event ) {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: "../php/client/json.php",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data, status) {
            $(this).modal('hide');
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

current validation code:

```
 $('#outcomeFormDialog form').validate(
 {
  rules: {
    amount: {
      money: true,
      required: true
    },
    comment: {
      required: false
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.control-group')
    .removeClass('success').addClass('error');
  },
  success: function(element) {
    element
    .addClass('valid').closest('.control-group')
    .removeClass('error').addClass('success');
  }
 });
```

As far as I understood, jquery validation's `success` corresponds to each form element rather than entire form - so checking entire form validation should be done some other way.

This is my form (mustache-driven):

```
<div id="outcomeFormDialog" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog">
    <form class="form-horizontal well" data-async data-target="#outcomeFormDialog" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add outcome</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="type" type="hidden" value="add_outcome" />
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="amount">Amount</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <span class="add-on">{{ currency }}</span>
                            <input type="text" name="amount" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="00.01" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="comment" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Comment here..." />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save outcome</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple popular issues and misconceptions regarding this plugin:

- You do not need a `submit` handler.  The `click` event of the `submit` button is automatically captured and handled by this plugin.
- [As per the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), you are supposed to put your `ajax` within the plugin's `submitHandler` callback option.

> **submitHandler**:  Callback,  Default: default (native) form submit
>  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form
>   is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default
>   submit. **The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it
>   validated.**

**Assuming your `ajax` is written properly, re-arrange your code into something more like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#outcomeFormDialog form').validate({  // initialize plugin
        rules: {
            amount: {
                // money: true, //<-- no such rule
                required: true
            },
            comment: {
                required: false // superfluous; "false" same as leaving this rule out.
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group')
                .removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.addClass('valid').closest('.control-group')
                .removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // form validates so do the ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: $(form).attr('method'),
                url: "../php/client/json.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data, status) {
                    // ajax done
                    // do whatever & close the modal
                    $(this).modal('hide');
                }
            });
            return false; // ajax used, block the normal submit
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/duAkn/**